# How do i redirect user to the login page if they visit my root url?

Tags: ruby, redirect, authentication, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Ruby 2.3 with Rails 5.  I have this in my config/routes.rb file

get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'

root '/login'

but upon loading my server, I’m getting the error

```
Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.
```

I want to redirect the user to the login page if they visit the root URL.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I went with

```
  root :to => redirect('/login')
```

The suggestion of doing teh controller#action is good, but I like the redirect directive because it allows me to change things in one place instead of having to edit things in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

For the root path, set it to controller#action instead of the string you have presently. Seems you have it on 'sessions#new'

Comment: If I change the controller#action pointed to by '/login', I will also have to change my root path, correct?  Is there a way I can define the login page in one place and have the root point at that?

Comment: you know, if you want the root to always be the login page, then you can add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your application controller

then you can go ahead and set your root to whatever you want. that way, after logging in, it'd redirect to that page

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply.  Am I adding anything else besides "before_action :authenticate_user!" or does that automatically redirect to the login page when visiting the root?

Comment: It's a built-in rails method so just add that

Comment: Unfortunately adding that to the top of my application controller does not redirect me to the login page when I visit the root URL.

Comment: That's weird. Are you using devise for user authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Change root 'login' to root 'sessions#new'

Think of "login" as the name of the route, what you actually want the user to do is go to the sessions controller and the new action within that controller